# kdenlive - select project video orientation

Tags: kdenlive

I have a project with two video clips, made with smartphone, one is horizontally aligned and the other vertically aligned.

I want my project to be horizontally aligned (landscape), but I can't find where to set it, and I don't know why kdenlive set my project settings according to my second video clip, the one that is vertically aligned (portrait). Therefore my landscape video is now cropped.

[image]

**How to set the project (project, not clip) video orientation, landscape ou portrait?**

I went to project settings and it didn't help, since it is already 16x9